# In Angular, how do you loop through two arrays to populate a third?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, foreach

I am using forEach to loop through two arrays (cake and frosting). An alert confirms the expected results.
How can the results be added to the 3rd array? (cakeOptions)
This fiddle shows the work so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/_StephenC/ov5syuwb/20/

Thanks

```
function CakeController($scope) {
$scope.cakes = [{
    name: 'chocolate',
    'price': 6
}, {
    name: 'yellow',
    'price': 5
}, {
    name: 'coconut',
    'price': 7
}
];
$scope.frostings = [{
    'name': 'chocolate',
        'price': 5
},

{
    'name': 'vanilla',
        'price': 5
}, {
    'name': 'coconut',
        'price': 8
}];

$scope.cakeOptions = [];

angular.forEach($scope.cakes, function (value, key) {
var thisCake = JSON.stringify(value.name);
angular.forEach($scope.frostings, function (value) {
var thisFrosting = JSON.stringify(value.name, value.value);
alert(thisCake + ' cake with ' + thisFrosting + ' frosting');
```

Comment: Inside the inner foreach loop, just push `thisCake ` and `thisFrosting` into the `cakeOptions` array.

Comment: Thanks Mohammed.
Adding: 
`$scope.cakeOptions.push({Cake: thisCake , Frosting: thisFrosting });`
worked fine.
(Not sure why earlier attempts failed)
Updated the fiddle as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a new fiddle that actually works and with the added example of populating a third box from an array of the combinations:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6q9qbqw6/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="cakeApp">
    <div ng-controller="cakeCtrl">
        <div id="one"><strong>Cakes</strong><br>
            <div class="order" ng-repeat="cake in cakes">
                {{cake.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="two"><strong>Frostings</strong><br>
            <div class="order" ng-repeat="frosting in frostings">
                {{frosting.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
            <div id="three"><strong>Combinations</strong><br>
            <div class="order" ng-repeat="cakeOption in cakeOptions">
                {{cakeOption}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var app = angular.module('cakeApp', []);
app.controller('cakeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.cakes = [{
        name: 'chocolate',
        price: 6
    }, {
        name: 'yellow',
        price: 5
    }, {
        name: 'coconut',
        price: 7
    }];

    $scope.frostings = [{
        'name': 'chocolate',
            'price': 5
    },

    {
        'name': 'vanilla',
            'price': 5
    }, {
        'name': 'coconut',
            'price': 8
    }];
    $scope.cakeOptions = [];

    angular.forEach($scope.cakes, function (value, key) {
        var thisCake = JSON.stringify(value.name);
        angular.forEach($scope.frostings, function (value) {
            var thisFrosting = JSON.stringify(value.name, value.value);
            $scope.cakeOptions.push(thisCake + ' cake with ' + thisFrosting + ' frosting');
        });
    });
}]);
```