# How can I show nested json elements in html angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I'm trying to show a JSON code into a table of html. I have this JSON:

```js
posts:[
  {
  "category":[],
  "status":[]
    
  },
  {
    "category":
    [
      {
        "ID_post":"2",
        "category":"5 Reasons",
        "ID_cat":"1"
        
      },
      {
        "ID_post":"2",
        "category":"Advertising",
        "ID_cat":"2"
        
      }
    ],
    "status":
    [
      {
        "ID_post":"2",
        "status":"Approved",
        "ID_stat":"1",
        "color":"red"
        
      },
      {
        "ID_post":"2",
        "status":"Placed",
        "ID_stat":"2",
        "color":"#1800fb"
        
      }
    ]
    
  }
]
```

I want to show the color of the status into a html table like this:

```html
<tr>
  <th>Web Status</th>
</tr>
<tbody ng-repeat="post in posts | startFrom: start | limitTo: limit">
  <tr>
    <td>{{post.status}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

It returns something like this in the second post:

```js
[{"ID_post":"2","status":"Approved","ID_stat":"1","color":"red"},{"ID_post":"2","status":"Placed","ID_stat":"2","color":"#1800fb"}]
```

But I need the color of each post. How can I get it? I tried with post.status.color but it doesn't work.
Can someone help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *all* you want to display in the table is the color of each status, one approach you can take is to capture the "status" data in a separate array, for example `$scope.statuses = posts[1].status`. Then loop through this array in your HTML:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="status in statuses| startFrom: start | limitTo: limit">
  <tr>
    <td>{{status.color}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

With your current data structure, `posts` is an array with two elements. The `ng-repeat` direct loops through each element in this array. The first element, `posts[0]`, is an object with two properties that are empty arrays. Therefore, the first `{{post.status}}` is empty. The second element, `posts[1]`, is an object again with properties "category" and status, each with populated arrays. With this second element, `{{post.status}}` will display all the data in `posts[1].status`.

So again, if all you need to display is the color of each status, it'd be easiest to capture `posts[1].status` in a separate variable. If you need to display the category data along with the status data, you may need to combine those two arrays into a single array. See this for an example: [In Angular, how do you loop through two arrays to populate a third?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25386860/in-angular-how-do-you-loop-through-two-arrays-to-populate-a-third)

Answer (score 0):

status is an array.

To access the color of each status you need to define an index, example:

```
post.status[0].color
```

Your data looks strange, I think the problem is that the post has more than one status.